# $F: P(X) \rightarrow P(Y)$ given as $F(A) = f(A)$ is an injective function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following exercise:

Prove that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is injective or surjective, then $F: P(X) \rightarrow P(Y)$ given as $F(A) = f(A)$ is an injective function.

The case in which f is injective I have already covered it, but in the case that $f$ was only surjective I have doubts about it, I am not sure if the statement is true, I hope you can help me if you have any counterexample or some hint of proof, thanks.

Comment: Consider $Y=\{y\}$.

Comment: if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $F(\{x_1\})=F(\{x_2\})$.

Comment: @lulu, but this is for the case where it is injective, right?

Comment: $f$ surjective $\implies$ $F$ injective is not true, but $f$ surjective $\implies$ $F$ surjective is.

Comment: I suspected it, thanks